# How long would it take for a beginning piano player to learn to play Bach Badinerie

Tags: piano, beginner

Would it be possible for a beginning piano player (in their late twenties) to learn to play the song (see video) exactly as it's played there, within a year of practice (practicing 30 minutes to an hour every day)?

Comment: Everyone learns at different speeds. If you want to learn it, just start, and you'll find out how long it takes.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that being able to remember all the keys to press, and doing so in a way that sounds quite fine to oneself, is not the same thing as making it sound alright to other people. Being able to "hear oneself" is a huge part of becoming a decent musician. I've given lessons to impatient adults who had in mind to play specific modest pieces, which were technically within their reach, but they could not _hear_ their own rhythmic and other inaccuracies. They just couldn't hear it.

Comment: Would teachers generally consider this song to be at an advanced level? So far, I learnt to play River Flows In You within 2 months with both hands (still need to practice timing and rhythm properly), that went actually pretty well. But in the song I posted here, there seems to be much more happening, and feels more daunting.

Comment: The Badinerie is originally written for orchestra with solo flute. Baroque accompagniment may become polyphonic and therefore difficult quickly, especially if several instruments have to be substituted. It may be worth to check several editions before deciding for one. (I don't like the interpretation from the video, but if your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Reminds me of the folk tale… a king sentences a slave to death [for some irrelevant infraction]. The slave asks the king to make a promise. If he can teach the king's horse to sing in a year, he should be freed. The king agrees. When asked, the slave explains, "A lot can happen in a year. The king might die; I might die; or the horse might learn to sing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody can set a timeline for you.  That depends on your talent, your commitment, and the quality of your strategies for learning.

I'd say that you can probably learn to perform that piece within a year.  To do so with that quality of phrasing and musicality-- that really is up to you.

Comment: Yes, as in that last sentence: you would most likely want to get considerable competent feedback about the _musicality_ of your rendition of the piece. Not just whether you played all the notes... which, yes, is already often challenging! :)